# Unable to add commit message using GUI Macvim

Tags: git, vim, macvim

When I use `git commit` using `mvim` as editor, the usual `COMMIT_MSG` file opens up in a new MacVim window, but when I write and exit the message, git ignored the commit message.

This issue does not happen if I use terminal `vim`, so I think there is no problem with my vim configuration.

What should I do? I use `iTerm` running on `zsh`

Comment: You can run macvim in your terminal with `mvim -v`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After googling for a while, I found that the solution is to simply tell git run `mvim` in foreground mode.

`git config --global core.editor "mvim -f"`